# spring integraion outbound gateway 's dynamic https URLs has problem

Tags: spring-integration

I want build a soft gateway,so I will provide my inner system some spring integration's url, and my system then send to the real destination's url.
here is my code. It's a outbound gateway, and I have set https url in inputchannel headers.

```
<int:channel id="inputChannel"/>
<int:channel id="outputChannel">
    <int:queue capacity="100"/>
</int:channel>

<int-http:outbound-gateway   request-channel="inputChannel"
                            url-expression="headers.dynamicUrl"
                           http-method-expression="POST"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                            reply-channel="outputChannel"

                           charset="UTF-8">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

and my java code is like this

```
MessageChannel inputChannel = context.getBean("inputChannel", MessageChannel.class);
    PollableChannel outputChannel = context.getBean("outputChannel", PollableChannel.class);
    inputChannel.send(msgWithHTTPsUrl);//msg with https Url https://www.example.net
    Message<?> replyMesg = outputChannel.receive();
    Message<?> toSend = MessageBuilder.withPayload(replyMesg.getPayload()).copyHeadersIfAbsent(replyMesg.getHeaders()).build();
    System.out.println(toSend);
    return toSend;
```

and program can print tosend msg. but the browser can't get reply.it says ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED.
Maybe the https://www.example.net use gzip compress. 
So how can I handld this, so I can make a soft gateway for my company's inner system?
thank you!

---

now, I add a rest-template to solve this error

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway   request-channel="inputChannel"
                        url-expression="headers.dynamicUrl"
                       http-method-expression="POST"
                       expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                        reply-channel="outputChannel"
                        rest-template="restTemplate"
                       charset="UTF-8">
```

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="sslFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="sslFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
</bean>
```

and I set ignore validation of server-side certificates, Here is my java code of httpclient

```
        @Component("httpClient")
    public class HttpClientFactory extends AbstractFactoryBean<HttpClient> {

        @Override
        public Class<?> getObjectType() {
            return HttpClient.class;
        }
        public HttpClient getInstance() throws Exception {
            return createInstance();
        }
        @Override
        protected HttpClient createInstance() throws Exception {

            RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setSocketTimeout(3000)
                    .setConnectTimeout(3000)
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(3000)
                    .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(true)
                    .build();

            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            TrustStrategy allTrust = new TrustStrategy() {
                public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, allTrust).build();

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig).build();
            return httpClient;
        }
```

but outbund-gateway get 4xx/5xx response when I use this httpclient,
and I write a HttpPost to test this httpclient, the response  is OK.
Is something I misunderstand of outbund-gateway? Or What other things I missed?

---

I write test case to test my spring integration app,  and the httpclient I inject to Spring integration.
the spring integration app get the error reply:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [https://www.npr.org/]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={content-length=0, http_requestMethod=POST, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@3afa4833, httpMethod=POST, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@3afa4833, respUrl=https://www.npr.org/, host=localhost:8080, http_requestUrl=http://localhost:8080/sihttp/mytest, connection=Keep-Alive, id=256ed96e-9c00-ecf4-9d1b-63f37635fb4a, contentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8, accept-encoding=gzip,deflate, user-agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.5.6 (Java/1.8.0_131), timestamp=1544368429831}]
```

and the httpClient visit https://www.npr.org/ directly has successful  return. The test code is like this:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(); // same httpclinet I inject in outbound gateway's rest-template
    HttpPost post=null;
    post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/sihttp/mytest"); // this post will goto my spring integration app, in spring integration app, I will map this  url to https://www.npr.ogr, and send out in outbound gateway
//   post = new HttpPost("https://www.npr.org/"); // npr.org can successful visit in this post
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(6000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(6000)
                .setSocketTimeout(6000).build();
        post.setConfig(requestConfig);
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if (httpEntity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
        }

        httpResponse.close();
```

in spring integration, httpclient execute with httpContext

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = this.httpClient.execute(this.httpRequest, this.httpContext);
```

and in HttpClient, it execute directly.

```
httpClient.execute(post);
```

Is this the reason of two different result?

Answer (score 1):

If the story is about GZIP, you should consider to inject into your `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` a different:

```
<xsd:attribute name="request-factory" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
Reference to a ClientHttpRequestFactory to be used by the underlying RestTemplate.
                ]]></xsd:documentation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                    <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory" />
                </tool:annotation>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

My recommendation is to use an `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`.

If even that doesn't help, please, share with us the whole stack trace to determine what may be missed.

Comment: I inject a httpclient to ignore validation of server-side certificates. but I still get 404 response in oubound gateway. I've add my code.

Comment: What error message you get from server? Can you consult with the rest service vendor what you may miss in your request? There is nothing wrong with your client so far. You just miss something what makes a server happy.

Comment: I have post my test code, and also the error message I get from server.

Comment: Maybe it’s time to set `contentType` header for JSON before HTTP Gateway? The same value you do in your raw test